# How to get account and contact of a particular case using soql query in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex, soql

I want to show accounts and contacts data of a particular case in a form. how can i query the same using soql query in salesforce. 
I have a custom object named Work_Order__c which is having a master-detail relationship with CASE object.
I am trying to write a below mentioned query, but the inner query is giving error.

```
select Id,Case__r.CaseNumber,Case__r.Description,Name,
Status__c,Priority__c,Description__c,City__c,Street__c,Zip__c,
(select Case__r.Account.Name, Case__r.Contact.Name from Work_Orders__r)
from Work_Order__c where Id = 'a024B0000025L6G'
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner query is giving you an error because Work_Orders__r isn't a table.  It is syntactic-sugar that gives you the list of all Work_Orders that are associated with a Case.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
SELECT Id,Name,Status__c,Priority__c,Description__c,City__c, Street__c,Zip__c,
       Case__r.CaseNumber, Case__r.Description,
       Case__r.Contact.FirstName,Case__r.Contact.LastName,Case__r.Contact.<Other_Contact_Fields>,
       Case__r.Account.Name, Case__r.Account.<Other_Account_Fields>
FROM Work_Order__c
WHERE Id = 'a024B0000025L6G';
```

My other recommendations is to avoid hard coding your Id.